# Get Parameters in php file when POST from Swift

Tags: php, swift

I'm trying to get parameters in my php file when I'm posting from SWIFT (login file)

This is my php file :

```
<? 
 $json = array();
 $json['username'] = $_POST['username'];
 $json['password'] = $_POST['password'];
 $json['result'] = "false";
 $json['id_familia'] = 148;
 $json['id_centre'] = 2;
 $json['web'] = "www.cec-escolalolivar.cat";
 echo json_encode($json); 
?>
```

This is swift code (of course I've tried with different options, sync, not sync, ....)

```
    let url : NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.cec-info.cat/app/config.inc.main_families_json.php")!
    let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
    let bodyData="data=xgubianas@gmail.com"
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = bodyData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main)
    {
        (response,data,error) in
        print (response as Any)

        if let data = data{
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print (json)
            }
            catch
            {
                print (error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where? Where is your php file?

Comment: Sorry, my php file has been not inserted...  This is                                        <?
 $json = array(); 
 $json['username']  = $_POST['username'];
 $json['password']   = $_POST['password'];
 $json['result']   = "false";
 $json['id_familia'] = 148;
 $json['id_centre']  = 2;
 $json['web']    = "www.cec-escolalolivar.cat";
 echo json_encode($json);
?>

Comment: __Edit__ your question please and paste code there

Comment: You should post the swift code issuing the `$_POST`request.

Comment: Hi all,  I've updated all code so you can check it. Thanks !!!